# Different flavours of Recursion, Usage of Reference/Global/pointer variables

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

There are certain recursive solutions which can only be done, by using Reference Type variables  ( Or pointers in C/C++ ) or using Global/Member variables.

I feel a pure recursive function should not modify the global state.

Is there any specific name for this kind of recursive solution (in memoization, we only cache), And Can we convert these to more natural type of recursion ?

***For ex: Max Sum Problem in a Binary Tree.***

You Can see that we are using `max[0] = Math.max(max[0]` across the calls.

```
public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        int max[] = new int[1]; 
        max[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        calculateSum(root, max);
        return max[0];
    }

    private int calculateSum(TreeNode root, int[] max) {
        if (root == null)
            return 0;

        int left = calculateSum(root.left, max);
        int right = calculateSum(root.right, max);

        int current = Math.max(root.val, Math.max(root.val + left, root.val + right));

        max[0] = Math.max(max[0], Math.max(current, left + root.val + right));

        return current;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The global/reference value is completely unnecessary. It is an artifact of a limitation in the programming language of the original implementation (C), in which it is syntactically awkward to return a pair of values.

I don't know Java well enough to know whether it has a generic pair class, like C++ does, but you could always use a class which has two integer members.

Try rewriting the recursive function with a prototype like:

```
Pair<int, int> walk(Treenode root, int maxpath);
```

and you'll see that no mutable variables are actually needed.